# How to replace or remove special characters from scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, special-characters

I just started learning scrapy and trying to make spider to grab some info from website and trying to **replace** or **remove** special characters in 'short_descr'

```
import scrapy


class TravelspudSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'travelSpud'
    allowed_domains = ['www.tripadvisor.ca']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attractions-g294265-Activities-c57-Singapore.html/'
    ]
    base_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.ca'

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):

        for items in response.xpath('//div[@class= "_19L437XW _1qhi5DVB CO7bjfl5"]'):

            yield {
                'name':        items.xpath('.//span/div[@class= "_1gpq3zsA _1zP41Z7X"]/text()').extract()[1],

                'reviews':     items.xpath('.//span[@class= "DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 _14_buatE _1dimhEoy"]/text()').extract(),

                'rating':      items.xpath('.//a/div[@class= "zTTYS8QR"]/svg/@title').extract(),

                'short_descr': items.xpath('.//div[@class= "_3W_31Rvp _1nUIPWja _17LAEUXp _2b3s5IMB"]'
                                       '/div[@class="DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 _3SccQt-T"]/text()').extract(),

                'place':       items.xpath('.//div[@class= "ZtPwio2G"]'
                                       '/div'
                                       '/div[@class= "DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 _3SccQt-T"]/text()').extract(),

                'cost':        items.xpath('.//div[@class= "DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 _3SccQt-T"]'
                                       '/div[@class= "DrjyGw-P _1SRa-qNz _2AAjjcx8"]'
                                       '/text()').extract(),
            }

        next_page_partial_url = response.css("div._1I73Kb0a").css("div._3djM0GaD").xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()

        if next_page_partial_url is not None:

            next_page_url = self.base_url + next_page_partial_url
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Character I'm trying to replace is `Hiking Trails • Scenic Walking Areas`. The dot in the middle decodes in csv file as `вЂў`
Everyting else works like a charm.

I've tried to use `.replace()`, but I'm getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: extract() method returns list. Try using extract_first() and then the replace method. Something like this .extract_first().replace(...)

Comment: @SagunShrestha, thank you! I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're removing these special characters just because they appear weirdly in a CSV file, then I suggest not removing them. Just simply add the following line in the `settings.py` file.

```
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8-sig'
```

This will print the special character in your CSV file.

Comment: Great solution, thank you! Everything works fine now